# How to balance the workload of teachers in OR-Tools (maximization of the minimum)

Tags: optimization, python, or-tools, cp-sat

I am very new to optimization and OR-Tools. I am trying to solve a very simple question.

Let's assume that we have $n$ students. Each student needs to be assigned to only one teacher as a supervisor. There are several constraints that are not very critical for now. However, there are two types of supervisors.
But at the same time, I am trying to keep the balance of the workload of the teachers as much as possible.

I am trying to write the objective but for some reason, it does not work correctly. I believe that I am missing something important.

```
model = cp_model.CpModel()

# Declare the variables.
x = []
for i in range(num_of_students):
    t = []
    for j in range(num_of_teacher):
        t.append(model.NewIntVar(0, 2, "x[%i,%i]" % (i, j))) #0 not supervisor, 1 1st type, 2nd type
    x.append(t)

workload =[]
for j in range(num_of_teacher):
    workload.append(sum([x[i][j] for i in range(num_of_students)]))

# Constraints
# Each student is assigned to EXACTLY one teacher.
[model.Add(sum(x[i][j] for j in range(num_of_teacher)) == 1)
for i in range(num_of_students)]

#objective
model.Maximize( min(workload))

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)
print (solver.ObjectiveValue())
```

When I run the code, each student (I have 11 students and 3 teachers) is assigned to only one teacher. But all of them are the same teacher. When I look at the workloads, it is [0, 0, 11].

However, system displays 11 as the ObjectiveValue. But min([0,0,11] is 0, right?.

I also tried to write the objective as
`model.Minimize( max(workload))` but all of the students assigned to only one teacher again.

Answer (score 6):

`min`, `max`, functions do not work in OR-Tools, you should use [AddMinEquality](https://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.html#cp_model.CpModel.AddMinEquality) instead:

```py
...
workload = []
for j in range(num_of_teacher):
    tmp = model.NewIntVar(0, num_of_students, "")
    model.Add(tmp == sum([x[i][j] for i in range(num_of_students)]))
    workload.append(tmp)

...
obj = model.NewIntVar(0, num_of_students, "")
model.AddMinEquality(obj, workload)
model.Maximize(obj)
```

Related links:

- https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1581
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62666474/or-tools-cpsolver-get-minimum-and-maximum-sum-or-absolute/62666907#62666907

Comment: Thank you for very quick answer. Now it works :)  I am not still trying to learn OR-tools but I think

 obj = model.NewIntVar(0, num_of_students, "")  should be
 obj = model.NewIntVar(0, num_of_teacher, "")

 right?

Comment: hmm, isn't workload related to num_of_students? obj is just the min of that

Comment: I really do not wan to take your time but can you briefly explain the logic?

Comment: I think I understand, thank you for explaining.... Do you know any tutorial like "OR tools for dummies" :)  Because I will face with lots of problem like it.. For example 
I want to ignore the type of supervision when counting the workload..

So in ideal conditions:
model.Add(tmp == sum([ x[i][j] for i in range(num_of_items_in_orders)]))
should be
model.Add(tmp == sum([ (x[i][j] > 0) for i in range(num_of_items_in_orders)]))
but it says: 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'BoundedLinearExpression'
Do you have any suggestion for it?